# Camunda mybatis custom query mapping file location

Tags: mybatis, camunda, mappings

I'm working on adding custom queries based on [sample](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/real-life/how-to/#process-engine-custom-queries-custom-mybatis-queries).

However when initializing the executor it is throwing a null pointer exception because it can't find the mapping.xml file.Any idea on how to overcome this? I have tried giving the full path like

```
commandExecutor = new MyBatisQueryCommandExecutor(processEngineConfiguration, "Users/a/Desktop/mappings/DeploymentMapper.xml");
```

Still it doesnt solve the issue. Do we have to add a mapping property in camuda-cfg.xml?  If so please provide a sample property definition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a full example [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/tree/master/snippets/custom-queries). The mapping has to be part of the resources of your war file.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I was actually following that sample, and i added the mapping.xml and the customMapper.xml to resources folder of my java application. but in  initSqlSessionFactory() method the inputStream is still returned null.

Comment: I did a little bit of debugging, in the override method of protected InputStream getMyBatisXmlConfigurationSteam() {
        return ReflectUtil.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
    }

Comment: it's throwing null for Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration() of below code block.

   
    private static ClassLoader getCustomClassLoader() {
    ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
    if(processEngineConfiguration != null) {
      final ClassLoader classLoader = processEngineConfiguration.getClassLoader();
      if(classLoader != null) {
        return classLoader;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Any hint on that?

Comment: Got it sorted. :) The files weren't in the correct place.